# Filter received results from an API with multiple filters

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm trying to create a faceted search but am having a hard time applying ALL of the filters requested. Right now I receive data from an API, let's say part of that data is features.  It's an object that has keys which are the features and values that can be false, null, '', true, and 'some helpful info'. I currently collect all of requested filters into an array, something like ('hasLasers', 'isAwesome', 'martianRequired').  I can filter on one, or each, but not all, at least I haven't been able to figure that out.  I need to check that the all of the array of filters are not null, false,  or '', not just one, but all.  Im not looking for an answer per-say but maybe a shove in the right direction, hopefully my description helps!

I've tried creating a do while loop that has a boolean and if one of the items in the array is false, it breaks, and if it is still true and reaches the array length it "should" add that item to an array, which just seems to add everything.  I also tried array.every where it should check that all return true but that didn't seem to work.  I did attempt a few other but I soon realized I was just testing on one filter or each filter...

```
arrFilters = ["hasWizards", "includesCheese", "moonView"]
apiResults.forEach(function(data) {
 const features = apiResults.features;
  Object.entries(features).forEach(
   ([key, value]) => {
    //need to find all values to arrFilters that are not null, false, or ''
   }
  );
})
```

API results look like:

```
const apiResults = [{
    id: 1,
    features: {
      hasWizards: true,
      moonView: "",
      includesCheese: false,
      moreUnicorns: null
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    features: {
      hasWizards: true,
      moonView: "Yes",
      includesCheese: true,
      moreUnicorns: null
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    features: {
      hasWizards: "Yup",
      moonView: true,
      includesCheese: true,
      moreUnicorns: null
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Are `"hasWizards", "includesCheese", "moonView"` these keys in the object you want to filter?

Comment: Yes, the user selects items they want to filter by, which is what the arrFilters becomes and all of the things they can select are keys in the object.

Comment: Can you also share `apiResults` value in the question?

Comment: Updated the question with apiResults valule

Comment: Given the API result you've shared, what would be the expected output?

Comment: added questionable api results to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to base the data on your description as opposed to your example, as they aren't aligned right now - the data is actually not valid, syntactically.

To fetch results where *all* filters are truthy, you can combine [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

The logic is *"For each piece of data, check if every feature from `arrFilters` evaluates to `true`"*.

```js
const apiResults = [{
    id: 1,
    features: {
      hasWizards: true,
      moonView: "",
      includesCheese: false,
      moreUnicorns: null
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    features: {
      hasWizards: true,
      moonView: "Yes",
      includesCheese: true,
      moreUnicorns: null
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    features: {
      hasWizards: "Yup",
      moonView: true,
      includesCheese: true,
      moreUnicorns: null
    }
  }
];

const arrFilters = ["hasWizards", "includesCheese", "moonView"];
const results = apiResults.filter(data => arrFilters.every(filter => data.features[filter]));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for!  I did try using array.every but apparently  I didn't have the logic just right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
arrFilters = ["hasWizards", "includesCheese", "moonView"]


const features = apiResults.node.features;

const checkResult = arrFilters.map(eachFilter => !features[eachFilter]).reduce((a,b)=> a&&b)
console.log(checkResult)
```

You might have to tweak `!features[eachFilter]` part with `!!features[eachFilter]` or keep it as same depending upon your use case

I am using `map` and `filter` functions to check if all of your conditions are met. The map function will create an array of `True` & `False`s depending on the value of that specific key in that object. I am adding a `!` operator to convert it to boolean truthy are falsy value.

Once I have this array of boolean I reduce them to a single value using js `reduce` function by applying logical `&&` to successive elements and see if all of them are `True`